How to Handle Masked Values in Neural Networks for Geospatial Data?
I am working on neural networks for oceanographic data and face challenges in dealing with masked values, which I set to NaN.. I can train a neural network model with 1D vertical profiles (e.g. temperature and salinity at different depths in the ocean) and 2D ocean surface data (e.g. sea surface temperature), where

In 1D data, values near the seafloor are masked by the ocean floor.
by the ocean floor.
In 2D data, masked values occur due to land masses.

I would like to understand the best practices for handling NaN values in these contexts. Specifically:

How can NaN values be handled within neural networks during training
without altering the original data by filling in arbitrary values?
Which neural network architectures or strategies are best suited to deal with
for dealing with masked values, where the masked values represent important
important information about the system?
If filling in masked values is unavoidable, is there any evidence or proof that adding
evidence that filling in masked values does not adversely affect the training of the
the training of the neural network?

Any technical advice or references would be greatly appreciated.
